# solr in javafx application instead of apache lucene

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I am making a search application using javafx . For indexing and searching i am using apache lucene . In place of lucene can is use apache solr .

What are the benefits of apache solr over apache lucene. Does solr provides its own indexing method or it uses lucene index for performing a search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache Solr is an search platform that runs on Servlet containers (such as Jetty, Tomcat) and uses Apache Lucene for indexing, so they are **not** the same thing.

You can think of Solr as more of a product or a ready to use system and Lucene as an engine/framework.

If you're looking to do indexing within your JavaFX application then you should stick to Apache Lucene, if you're considering a server-side approach to searching and indexing Solr could be an interesting idea.

You can check up more info and comparisons on Lucene and Apache at the following pages:

[Lucene vs Solr](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-vs-solr.html)

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

[Difference between solr and lucene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704644/difference-between-solr-and-lucene)

Comment: Is solar compatible with Microsoft.net technologies also?

Comment: Solr itself runs only within the JVM but there are client Solr APIs for .NET - check http://wiki.apache.org/solr/IntegratingSolr