# Looking for pylucene tutorial

Tags: pylucene

I finally was able to install the latest version of pylucene, though I'm not able to locate tutorials or examples on how to do some basic funtionalities like indexing, specifying the query and retrieving documents.

Answer (score 2):

According to the official Apache Lucene website: "PyLucene is a Python extension for accessing Java LuceneTM. Its goal is to allow you to use Lucene's text indexing and searching capabilities from Python. It is API compatible with the latest version of Java Lucene..." - so I would suggest you to learn Lucene API in Java.

In addition, the official site also offers PyLucene samples:
https://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/features.html

Finally, I would recommend you to consider using PySolr / Solr instead of PyLucene / Lucene, as discussed and answered in another post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15706624/9263939